# How to enable prevent default again in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Html code is,

```
 <a title="Delete" onclick="if (confirm('Delete selected item?')){ return true; }else{ event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();};" class="delete" href="link to delete page">
 </a>
```

Instead of this alert, I want give my alert function based on certain conditions and in that user confirms the option, it goes to the delete page.

My Jquery code is,

```
$('.delete').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   var a = url.split('id_product=');
   var next = a[1];
   var id=next.split('&');    
   var base_url = $("#ajaxbase").val();
   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",    
      url : base_url+"modules/sample/ajax/sample.php",  
      data: {id:id[0]}      
   }).done( function( response ) {
      var res=$.trim(response); 
      if ( res == '1' ) {
         if ( confirm('This Product is configured in chain.Deleting this product will affect your chain.Are you sure to do this?') ) {
        return true;            
         } else {
        return false;
         }
      } else if ( res == '2' ) {
         if ( confirm('Are you sure to delete this product?') ) {
        return true;
         } else {
        return false;
         }
      }
 });
```

My confirmation message is displayed, but if the user confirms it, then it didn't go to the delete page. can anyone help me please.

Comment: Typically with buttons such as this, I'd use a <span> tag to mimic the behaviour of a button, then you'd have full control of it's event bubbling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with having greater control on a non-`<a>` anchor element. Typically good if you wish to have full control over the behaviour of a given element, also I do think it's just *cleaner*.

Important to note, the `window.location.href` at the end, to proceed with the original indented behaviour.

```
<span class="delete" data-linkto="somepage.php">Delete</span>

<script>
    $('.delete').on('click', function() {

    var 
        url = $(this).data("linkto"),
        a = url.split('id_product='),
        next = a[1],
        id = next.split('&'),
        base_url = $("#ajaxbase").val(),
        verifyIfOne = confirm('This Product is configured in chain. '+ 
                              'Deleting this product will affect your chain. '+
                              'Are you sure to do this?'),
        verifyIfTwo = confirm('Are you sure to delete this product?'),
        Accepted = false;

       $.ajax({

          //Headers
          type : "POST",    
          url : base_url + "modules/sample/ajax/sample.php",  
          data: { id:id[0] }    

       }).done( function( response ) {

          var res = $.trim(response); 

          if ( res == '1' ) {
             if ( verifyIfOne ) {
                Accepted = true;         
             }
          } 

          if ( res == '2' ) {
             if ( verifyIfTwo ) {
                Accepted = true;
             }
          }
     /**
      *  User has agreed to go through with 
      *  the deletion.
     **/
     if ( Accepted )
         window.location.href = url;

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return false after the ajax call and handle the result in the ajax call different Because that the ajax call is asyn and therefor it will not wait for it to return true/false

**Edit this might be what you are looking for**

```
$('.delete').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   var a = url.split('id_product=');
   var next = a[1];
   var id=next.split('&');    
   var base_url = $("#ajaxbase").val();
   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",    
      url : base_url+"modules/sample/ajax/sample.php",  
      data: {id:id[0]}      
   }).done( function( response ) {
      var res=$.trim(response); 
      if ( res == '1' ) {
         if ( confirm('This Product is configured in chain.Deleting this product will affect your chain.Are you sure to do this?') ) {
           window.location.href = url ;
         } 
      } else if ( res == '2' ) {
         if ( confirm('Are you sure to delete this product?') ) {
            window.location.href = url ;
         }
      }
     return false;
 });
```